# How do I make my email invisible in my profile of Mathematics StackExchange?

Tags: support, profile-page, privacy

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/91129/dosomemaths

The above website is my profile of Mathematics StackExchange (not my Mathematics Meta).

Is my email visible in my profile?

If yes, how do I make it invisible?

Comment: It is not currently visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The information labeled `private` in your profile (including your email address) is visible only to **you**, to the **[moderators](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)** (those with a  diamond sign), and **some of [SE employees](http://stackexchange.com/about/team)** (namely, those with a diamond on Math site).

You can check this yourself by viewing your profile from another browser or computer on which you are not logged in to SE (or from browser's private / incognito   mode).

By the way, you are not *required* to give SE your email. The registration form accepts anything that looks remotely like an email address: `something@and.more`. The only drawback is that you won't have email as a way to recover  forgotten password.

Comment: Who are "moderators" and where are the "diamond sign" found?

Comment: Oh I get it. They are these people right?http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: @Dosomemaths: That is right.